# Wordpress. Как отсортировать посты в обратном порядке?

Tags: wordpress, сортировка

Посты в рубриках по умолчанию выводятся сверху новые, снизу старые. Надо сделать, чтобы было наоборот. В category.php вот такой код. Пробовал добавить туда строку (вторая строка). Посты сортируются, но в категориях начинают выводится абсолютно все посты и с других категорий тоже. Подскажите, как сделать правильно?

```
<h1><?php wp_title(''); // Заголовок категории ?></h1>
                **<?php query_posts('order=ASC' ); ?>**
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // если посты есть - запускаем цикл wp ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('loop'); // для отображения каждой записи берем шаблон loop.php ?>
                <?php endwhile; // конец цикла
                else: echo '<h2>Нет записей.</h2>'; endif; // если записей нет, напишим "простите" ?>    
                <?php pagination(); // пагинация, функция нах-ся в function.php ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строкой query_posts('order=ASC' ); ты перезаписал основной запрос. Тебе надо

```
 global $query_string;
 query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' );
```

Но тогда будут выводиться впереди самые старые в данной рубрике (а новые - на n-ной странице) 
А если тебе надо просто поменять последовательность вывода на странице (но не самые старые вообще в начало) - не помню, есть ли такая функция встроенная в wordpress, но можно взять глобальный массив `$wp_query->posts` и просто запустить его перебор в обычном цикле в ту или другую сторону, присваивая `$post = $wp_query->posts[$i];` (например, если через for этот массив прогоняешь) и `setup_postdata($post);` при необходимости. Можно также и просто отсортировать этот массив, прежде чем отправлять в цикл. В общем, как-то так

```
global  $wp_query, $post;
for($i=count($wp_query->posts)-1; $i>=0; $i--){
  $post= $wp_query->posts[$i]; setup_postdata($post);  
  get_template_part('loop');
}
```

Если нигде не ошибся - должно сработать

Comment: Вставил вместо той строки первый кусок кода и теперь он говорит что нет записей. Что-то тут не так. Мне нужно выводить вообще ВСЕ записи в обратном порядке от старых на первой странице до новых в конце

Comment: Если ты о 1ом - попробуй вот так
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' );
(видно '&' пропустил, хотя видел примеры и без него. Пример отсюда https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts ),

Comment: если не получится - покажите, что находится в переменной `$query_string`

Comment: Что - я сам не помню, но это можно посмотреть, выведя ее на экран, например через print_r(); (или echo ).