# Сортировка постов в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, сортировка

Подскажите, как правильно сделать выборку постов в вордпрессе. Мне необходимо получить последние три поста из категории (сортировка DESC), а затем их вывести так, чтобы старый пост оказался первым и далее в возрастающем порядке к новым (т.е. уже в обратном порядке ASC). 
Безуспешно экспериментировала с массивами аргументов в WP_Query. Еще пробовала цикл с обратным отсчетом [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426266/wordpress-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5?answertab=active#tab-top) с похожей задачей, но он не работает.

Comment: просто переверните массив постов с помощью [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: сразу после запроса перед началом цикла пишу $first_query = array_reverse($first_query); - не работает. точнее, страница белая

Comment: насколько понимаю, `$first_query` - это не массив постов

Comment: $first_query - это сам запрос, с которым работаю. вот, собственно, как он выглядит `$first_query = new WP_Query( $query_string.'&cat=96&posts_per_page=3&order=DESC');`

Answer (score 2):

попробуй просто:

```
query_posts($query_string.'&post_per_page=3');
```

по-умолчанию WP и так выводит последние посты, нужно только ограничить сколько.
…с учетом даты